# Adding a new span element to the label and writing an increment in the span for each new fieldset

Tags: jquery, increment

I have a plugin for cloning fieldsets in form. For each new fieldset, the plugin generates a new fieldset element with the same classes and subelements. In the beginning, I have only one fieldset and probably that is my problem.

I want to have a new span element in ".myClass" and in this span number, for every new +1.
I have:
Label
Label
Label

and I want to have:
Label 1
Label 2
Label 3
...

I have found jQuery code and ist working, but for each new fieldset set number 1:

```
$(".myClass").each(function(i) {
    $(this).append($("<span>"+(i+1)+"</span>"));
});
```

I think the problem is because I have only one fieldset in the beginning. When I click and clone a new filedset, jQuery sees the same element.

Any solution/hint/help?

Answer (score 0):

Can you please share your code? I don't get any idea.
As per my understand
If you find the length of total span inside your myclass then Your issue will resolved

Like `$(".myClass > span").length`

Or Inside foreach
`$(".myClass").each(function() { $(this).children('span').length });`

Comment: Hi, thank you for your support. This is my fieldset: `<fieldset class="custom-fieldset first">
    <legend>Label<span>1</span></legend>    
</fieldset>`
This fieldset I can duplicate. I added this span element with jQuery and want to change the number for each new fieldset. Probably, my code works only when see an array, but not in my case. I hope I describe it better ...

Comment: Whenever you add span element find the **total fieldset** exists in your class. 
`$(".myClass > fieldset").length` and this will gives you total filedset and add that count in your span